# How to access Object (PrintSystemJobInfo) from another Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, printing

i have a STA-Thread which adds a PrintJob to a PrinterQueue. This PrintJob should be monitored and i figuered a Timer would be the right thing to do. But obviously i cannot access the PrintSystemJobInfo-Object in the timer-thread.

How can i solve this situation?

I got the idea that i have to use a synchronized object but i don't know how to and i'm not sure if this will solve my problem... Or is there another technique (dispatcher maybe?) i can make use of?

Is it possible to make the timer STA so i can create the printjob in the timer thread (sta is required for printqueue.addjob)? But i guess this would be a workaround...

Any help much appreciated...

thx, effdee

edit:
some pseudocode:

```
class WcfService
{
 public int ServiceFunc() {
  Thread staThread = new Thread(myObj.myFunc);
  staThread.setSTA() and start()
  staThread.join()

  return myObj.status;
 }
}
```

-

```
class myObj
{
 public int status;
 public PrintSystemJobInfo printJob;
 public Dispatcher d;

 public void myFunc()
 {
  d = CurrentDispatcher;

  printJob = printQueue.AddJob(...);
  if (printJob == null) status = 0;
  else status = 1;      

  Timers.Timer timer = new Timer(invokeTimer);
  timer.Start();
 }

 public void invokeTimer(args)
 {
  d.Invoke(new Action(() => { timerFunc(args) }));
 }

 public void timerFunc(args)
 {
  //access printJob problem here ;)

  writePrintJobDetailsToDatabase();
 }
}
```

Comment: If you have an STA thread then you almost must have a message pump.  So a synchronous timer will work just fine.  Use a Winforms Timer or a WPF DispatcherTimer.

Comment: honestly i have no experience with sta-threads or "message pump"... just added some pseudocode to my question... message pump still relevant?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4271581/17034

Comment: problem avoided (see my other comment)... anyways i really appreciate your support... thx

Answer (score 1):

<s>You could expose the PrintSystemJobInfo Object to both threads and lock it when you use it. This should suspend the use of the object in a thread if the other one is using it.</s>

wait, nevermind. You need to make a method, addJob, in your mainthread (with STA) which calls AddJob(). In the other thread you can invoke that method with Dispatcher.Invoke and run the method on the main thread.

Or just do this:

```
void Thread2()
{
   Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => 
   {
       PrintSystemJobInfo.AddJob();
       //or any other methods you want executed on the main thread
   }
}
```

Comment: big thx for effort! looks good ;) i'm gonna try and give feedback... actually i have a wcf service which creates the STA thread. but it doesn't matter in this scenario, does it?

Comment: no, it doesn't matter. You do have to check if the Dispatcher object you're using is the dispatcher from the main thread.

Comment: i tried and sadly was unsuccessful... edited my code in the question to my current implementation of the dispatcher-logic... the idea is that the wcf-service responds to the client but the server checks the printer-status (even after the response - hence the timer/threads...) i don't know why but currently it seems the timer doesn't execute... any hint much appreciated

Comment: you could try to use a System.Timers.Timer and follow this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Comment: thx for your comment, but we now changed the system and created a workaround for the threading-problem... i got an idea how it should work and hopefully will be able to implement it correctly in the next project... thx again (would vote up since it helped me but i got not enough rep...)